# jquery regexp - regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I separate my string by regex match()? 
I want use only jQuery RegEx.

```
var MyStr = 'BeginStr ABCDEF EndStr' // The result should: ABCDEF
```

How can I separate "ABCDEF"?

Below is a solution, but I like to improve it, how can I eliminate the function replace()?
I want use only one time the function match().

```
var MyStr = 'BeginStr ABCDEF EndStr';  // The result should:  ABCDEF
sRegEx = /BeginStr.*?(?=EndStr)/;
var sResult = String(MyStr.match(sRegEx)); // It results: BeginStr ABCDEF
var sMenuPoint = String(MyStr.match(sRegEx)).replace(/BeginStr/, ''); // It results: ABCDEF
alert(sResult);
```

Thanks in advance, 
Sandro.

Comment: The code example doesn't use jQuery, just plain JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry.  I correct my string: The string to cut is between "BeginStr" and "EndStr".
var MyStr = 'any string BeginStr ABCDEF EndStr other string';

Comment: Thank you, it works :) 
But I still would like to know whether it would be feasible with match ()?
Here is the corrected string:
var MyStr = 'any string BeginStr ABCDEF EndStr other string';

Answer (score 2):

Using simple `replace()` function will do it for you along with group capturing(`$1`, `$2`, etc):

```
sResult = MyStr.replace(/.*BeginStr(.*?)(?=EndStr).*/, "$1");
```

or

```
sResult = MyStr.replace(/.*BeginStr(.*?)EndStr.*/, "$1");
```

Comment: Although I agree with your solution, OP asked 'how can I eliminate the function replace()?'

Comment: @aduch I thought by 'imporove it' he meant to use only one function, can be either `replace` or `match`. May be I was confused!!

Comment: Maybe I'm the one confused anyways +1.